# Set transparent background when background is not constant color in irfanview

Tags: colors, background, transparent

I have a photo, and I attempted to set the background to transparent.  However, the background is not a constant color, that is, there are slight variations in it.  I went through the process of setting the background to transparent, by selecting the transparency color upon saving as a GIF.  But as you can guess, only a few pixels in the background were made transparent.

So I do I select a range of pixels for transparency, in irfanview?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Paint Bucket to fill the area with white. Play with the Tolerance value till it fills the area you want. (Use [Ctrl]Z to undo it till you get it right.) Then set the white area to transparent.